# How to show results based on sql result data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I'm using Closure tree idea in my new website.
In one of the show views I want to select data by the id (1-level descendant) or if the id is null the first level. 
How do I connect sql with set result?

The Query:

```
select id,name 
from tags t 
join tag_hierarchies th (t.id = th.ancestor_id) 
where t.id=nvl(?,0) and th.generations=1
```

Code so far(problem on app/views/show.erb):

db/schema.rb:

```
  create_table "tags" do |t|
    t.string "name",  :null=>false
    t.boolean "isCat", :default => true
  end

  create_table "tag_hierarchies", :id => false do |t|
    t.integer "ancestor_id", :null => true
    t.integer "descendant_id", :null => false
    t.integer "generations", :null => false
  end

  add_foreign_key(:tag_hierarchies, :tags, :column => 'ancestor_id')
  add_foreign_key(:tag_hierarchies, :tags, :column => 'descendant_id')
```

app/models/tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :name, :isCat

  validates :name, uniqueness: false, allow_blank: false
end
```

app/models/Tag_Hierarchie.rb

```
class TagHierarchie < ActiveRecord::Base
  #attr_accessible :ancestor_id, :descendant_id, :generations
end
```

app/views/show.erb

```
<% provide(:title, category_name_or_constant(@tags)) %>
<h1><%= category_name_or_constant(@tags)%></h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= for(<<here goes the sql by the Closure tree >>) do |f| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add static method (or scope, if you prefer) to your Tag model:

**app/models/tag_hierarchy.rb**

```
class TagHierarchy
  belongs_to :tag, foreign_key: :ancestor_id
end
```

**app/models/tag.rb**

```
class Tag
  has_many :tag_hierarchies, foreign_key: :ancestor_id

  def self.descendants(id = nil)
    id ||= 0
    self.where(id: id).joins(:tag_hierarchies).where(tag_hierarchies: {generations: 1})
  end
end
```

Create a controller:

`rake g controller TagsController`

Add code to your controller:

**app/controllers/tags_controller.rb**

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @descendants = Tag.descendants
  end

  def show
    @descendants = Tag.descendants(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then use all the stuff in your views:

**app/views/tags/show.html.erb**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= @descendants.each do |tag| %>
        <%= link_to tag.name, tag %>
        <%# you can also use tag.tag_hierarchies here %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

I suggest you read some tutorials and/or docs on Rails:

[Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

[Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

[Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)